# Rewrite Question Mark in Post Template to Make it Pretty URL

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, urls, rewrite-rules

I hope you all are doing well and staying safe during these times.

I was wondering if someone can help me figure out how to remove the question mark (?) in the URL.

The URL I am trying to rewrite looks like this: https://website.com/windows/post-name/?download

The URL I'd like to have: https://website.com/windows/post-name/download

That's the code I have tried but didn't work, I get an Internal Server Error

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpa5413_init' );
function wpa5413_init()
{
add_rewrite_rule(
    'windows/([^/]+)/?/?download',

    'windows/$matches[1]/download',

    'top' );
}
```

Please let me know what you think?

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what each part of the URL is? Do you have Pages, Categories, Posts, ...?

Comment: If possible, please provide the your code that is needed to be fixed. It is much easier for us to give opinions with more details given.

Comment: @simongcc I have updated the question with the code I have tried

Comment: @WebElaine /windows is a name post type  and   /post-name is a custom post type. Yes I have pages, categories and normal posts. I have updated the question with the code I have tried but didn't work

Comment: What is generating the `?download` query string?

Comment: @WebElaine Nothing, it's empty.

Comment: Right, but it's coming from somewhere. Deactivating all plugins and switching to a default theme, then turning them on one by one and checking in an Incognito window, should help you determine which one. If it's not there, it could be in an .htaccess or server config.